# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting the above error when I run my function. The goal is when a user enters a number in a  search box it should zoom to that number in the visualization. Below is my code -

```
function zoom1() {
 var input1 = document.getElementById("myInput1").value; //value from searchbox
  console.log("input from searchbox :"+input1);

 d3.json("intervals.json", function(alldata)  // entering json file  to look for oid
 {
    // console.log("all data from json"+alldata);
    var i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < alldata.records.length; i++)  //for loop for getting the "oid"  alldata.records.length;
    {
    
      conceptid1 = alldata.records[i].eag;  //saving all the oid in conceptid
      console.log("conceptid1: "+conceptid1);
      var conceptid2 = conceptid1.toString();
      console.log("conceptid2: "+conceptid2);
      if (conceptid2  === input1) //if the user input1 matches conceptid2
      {
         console.log("inside if conceptid2:"+conceptid2);
        
         console.log(document.getElementById(conceptid2).dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))); // zoom
      }

    }

 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you share the console log for `conceptid2`?

By the way, use ES6 syntax. It's a newer and better way to write JS. Here is your code written in ES6:

```js
const zoom = () => {
    let value = document.querySelector("#myInput1").value;
    console.log(`Input ${value}`);

    d3.json("intervals.json", (alldata) => {
        const { records } = alldata;

        for (let i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
    
            const conceptId = records[i].eag.toString();

            console.log(`Concept ID: ${conceptId}`);
            
            if (conceptId  === value) {
                // Your stuff   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Anyways didn't want to come on too hard but I hope this helps :)